# Convert x => array.Contains(x) expression into x=> x == 1 || x ==2

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Assuming that array is an array of integers:

```
var array = new [] { 1, 2 }
```

And let's say there is an object name *Some*, with properties:

```
public class Some
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

I need a way to convert:

```
Expression<Func<Some, bool>> exp = x => array.Contains(x.Id)
```

expression into:

```
Expression<Func<Some, bool>> exp = x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 2
```

**UPDATE**

I already have an extension method on list which generates wanted result from a list: What I am asking is, given expression 1 how could I convert it to expression 2. I don't want to push other team members to use extension instead of normal contains method.

my extension method:

```
array.SafeContainsExpression<Some, string>(nameof(Some.Id));
```

and the code:

```
    public static Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> SafeContainsExpression<TModel, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> list, string propertyName)
    {
        var argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
        var selector = Expression.Property(argParam, propertyName);

        Expression left = null;
        foreach (var value in list)
        { 
            var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));
            var right = Expression.Equal(selector, valueExpression);

            if (left == null)
                left = right;

            left = Expression.OrElse(left, right);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(left, argParam);
    }
```

**SOLUTION (From accepted answer)**

```
public class SafeExpressionsVisitor : LinqKit.ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Method.Name == "Contains" && m.Arguments.Count == 2)
        {
            var list = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(m.Arguments[0]).Compile()();
            var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)m.Arguments[1];
            Expression left = null;
            foreach (var value in list)
            {
                var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(value);
                var right = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, valueExpression);

                if (left == null)
                {
                    left = right;
                    continue;
                }

                left = Expression.OrElse(left, right);
            }

            return left;
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(m);
    }
}


public class ExpressionTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Shoul_Convert_With_Visitor()
    {
        var array = new[] { 1, 2 };

        Expression<Func<A, bool>> exp = x => array.Contains(x.Id);

        var safeExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<A, bool>>(
            new SafeExpressionsVisitor().Visit(exp.Body),
            exp.Parameters);

        var func = safeExp.Compile();

        Assert.True(func(new A { Id = 1 }));
        Assert.True(func(new A { Id = 2 }));
        Assert.False(func(new A { Id = 3 }));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by convert? Why not replace?

Comment: Why, though? If this is some kind of optimization pass, you'd be better off replacing it with `HashSet.Contains`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy this is a pseudo code, value of array is changed at run time. I think that I need an `ExpressionVisitor` that will get value of the array and for each value create expression from `Expression.Equal` and chain them with `Expression.OrElse`. but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I want this to query RavenDB that doesn't support `contains` method

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902851/34092 an option?

Comment: Fair enough. Be careful, though, that the resulting expression tree is linear in the size of the array, which can easily cause problems evaluating it if you're testing for many values. I don't know if RavenDB has an efficient `IN` operator you could use (or something comparable to it).

Comment: @mjwills actually I am using Repository pattern, and client where I am calling this method doesn't knows anything about RavenDB special methods, but: `Contains` operator to `IN` operator converter also could work as a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397777/implementing-the-repository-and-service-pattern-with-ravendb may be worth a read.

Comment: And that is why Repository pattern is the dumbest thing ever. NOTE In Repository pattern you should not expose IQueryable.

Comment: When you use a Repository then that is the place to solve this, and where you _do_ know about your type of Db.

Comment: @MerdanGochmuradov I made an edit on my answer but not sure if it is as generic as you would like.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I thing he is not really using Repository pattern but one of many IQueriable<Some> Get(); or similar implementations. This is not really I Repository but a lot of people call it that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion can work you can build an expression like so.

```
 Expression<Func<A, bool>> exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<A, bool>>(
                array.Select(i=>Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(p1,"Id"),Expression.Constant(i))).Aggregate((a,i)=> a == null? i:Expression.OrElse(a,i)),p1);
```

EDIT
This will convert the example but for more generic stuff you need to cover more cases of Expression tree.

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2 };

            Expression<Func<A, bool>> exp = x => array.Contains(x.Id);
            Expression<Func<A, bool>> exp2 = x => x.Id == 1 || x.Id == 2;


            var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A));

            var exp3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<A, bool>>(ExpressionVisitor.Visit(new []{ exp.Body }.ToList().AsReadOnly(), (m) => {
                if (m.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
                {
                    var method = (MethodCallExpression)m;
                    if (method.Method.Name == "Contains" && method.Arguments.Count == 2)
                    {
                        var items = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(method.Arguments[0]).Compile()();
                        var prop = ((MemberExpression)method.Arguments[1]);
                        return ((IEnumerable<int>)items).Select(i => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(prop.Expression, prop.Member.Name), Expression.Constant(i))).Aggregate((a, i) => a == null ? i : Expression.OrElse(a, i));

                    }
                }
                return m;
            })[0],exp.Parameters);


            var func = exp3.Compile();

            Console.WriteLine(func(new A { Id = 1 }));
            Console.WriteLine(func(new A { Id = 2 }));
            Console.WriteLine(func(new A { Id = 3 }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have made an ExpressionVisitor based on your answer, work like a charm )), will update my question to show the solution.

Comment: @MerdanGochmuradov Just one note be there might be some edge cases witch are not covered so do a lot of testing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Expression<Func<Some, bool>> exp = x => array.Contains(x.Id)
```

You can write:

```
var filters = array.Select<int, Expression<Func<Some, bool>>>(i =>
  x => x.Id == i);

Expression<Func<Some, bool>> exp = filters.OrTheseFiltersTogether();
```

Using my classic method:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrTheseFiltersTogether<T>(
  this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstFilter = filters.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstFilter == null)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> alwaysTrue = x => true;
        return alwaysTrue;
    }

    var body = firstFilter.Body;
    var param = firstFilter.Parameters.ToArray();
    foreach (var nextFilter in filters.Skip(1))
    {
        var nextBody = Expression.Invoke(nextFilter, param);
        body = Expression.OrElse(body, nextBody);
    }
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very few query providers actually support `Invoke`.  Almost all just throw when they come across it.