# DAL, Model Layer, EF code-first and business logic, how do they fit together?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-access-layer

Bit per bit, I am undestanding and becoming more proficient with ASP.NET MVC4. However I'm still failing to be clear in my mind concerning this very important point.  Let us say that I have a model :

```
public class WorkPaper
{
    public int WorkPaperID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description {get ; set; }
    public bool verified {get; set;}
    public DateTime dateAdded {get; set;}

}
```

I use this model with Entity Framework code first approach and I have the following DB Context :

```
public class NicodemeContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<WorkPaper> Workpapers { get; set; }
}
```

What I don't understand is : what is the Model Layer and what is the Data Access Layer. To me the WorkPaper class tends to be part of the DAL since I designed it and choosed my properties names and types (navigations property etc...) to fit the EF pattern. But the problem is that if i'm right, I really don't see where I should put the business logic.

In that specific case, if I want to add a rule saying that a Workpaper cannot be sent if it hasn't been verified and an other rule saying that if it's been added more than 2 weeks ago it can't be submitted (strange rules but that's just an example). Where should I add them ? Do I have to create an other class, but then where should I put it and what should it contain ? Isn't it going to be very redundant with the class I already have ? But in the other hand, since that class is "database oriented", wouldn't it be messy to add business rules there ?

My point is really in understanding where I have to put my business logic and to understand the difference between the DAL and the model. I have difficulties to identify the DAL and the Model Layer since their look very similar to me. I would like to do things the correct way.

(Basically, I don't know where to code "my program" with MVC ! I'm not comfortable as soon as I want to code the functionality I'm actually interested in. I feel like i'm not doing the things right)

Comment: Well, I have a better understanding thank to that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049363/difference-between-repository-and-service-layer It seems that the key is to put everything in a Service Layer.

Comment: I went through a lot of tutorials on MVC, Unit testing, mocking, Ioc etc...but it's only now that I begin to understand how I can use them in my projects. It may sound obvious but the pattern of using Service Layer is not natural to me, I'm not coming from a web development background and I used to develop "simple" standalone applications.

Comment: Please give your question a **meaningful title**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no single "right" way to do this.  There are probably a number of "wrong" ways, but as with most things much of it is "it depends".

You will find a lot of opinions on this.  And much of that depends on how you are approaching it.  For instance, @Tarzan suggests using your model for both business logic and data layer entities.  Others, suggest creating separate Entity objects, business objects, and view model objects.

If you're making a relatively simple, CRUD type application then you can probably do as @Tarzan suggests and have few problems.  However, in more complex applications you start to run into problems doing it this way.  For instance, what happens when your business logic is different from your data logic?  If you combine them into a single set of entities, then you are forced to make the logic the same everywhere, or spend a lot of time retrofitting.

The most flexible approach is to keep your Presentation, Business, and Data layers completely separate.  In this way, the requirements of (for example) the UI don't need to match the other layers.  (Here's a simple example, imagine that for some kinds of objects, a particular field is allowed to be null, but not for others.  Your data layer would only know that the field is nullable, while your business layer would know that certain objects can't be null).

However, that approach can have a lot of overhead, and require what seems like duplicate code in each layer... creating a lot of extra effort, which is often times not worth it for small or simple applications.

One key thing to remember is that MVC is a Presentation pattern.  That means it ONLY concerns itself with the user interface.  The "model" is typically considered to be a "view model", which is the model the view uses.  This model is customized for the views requirements.  For instance, by using Data Attributes that you would not put on a data model.

If you consider MVC to be strictly presentational, then MVC doesn't care what kind of data access you're using, nor does it care what kind of business layer you're using.  It could be a service layer, or a repository, or a business objects library (such as CSLA).

A common pattern in MVC applications is to use a service layer of some type, or a repository if you're simply doing CRUD operations.  There is typically some kind of mapping system between each layer, using technologies like AutoMapper or custom build mapping classes.

The point here is simply this.  MVC doesn't concern itself with business and data, so don't get yourself all worked up over how these fit into an MVC application.  They don't, or at least they don't other than with very basic interfacing.

Your application is a collection of objects, in what can be considered an architecture.  This architecture is made up of different layers.  MVC, Service, Data, etc.. MVC may be the primary user interface, but that doesn't mean everything else is also MVC.

Comment: Thank you very much Erik !! You clearly understood what my problem was and you are absolutely right, I was also confused concerning the role of MVC. To me everything was and needed to be MVC in a MVC application. I'm very thankful because thank to your answers I feel much more comfortable. That was exactly the explanations I needed !

Comment: Great answer. Especially the part that there is not always a "right" way to do it. It certainly depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the NicodemeContext class in the DAL and the WorkPaper class in the Model Layer.

- The Model Layer is where you define your business domain. This is where your business logic goes.
- The Data Access Layer is where you read and write to the database and populate the objects from your Model Layer.

A useful technique is to use partial classes in the Model. In one partial class keep everything that might be written by a code generator and everything handwritten in the other partial class. For example, if you use a tool to generate a partial WorkPaper class it will usually contain all of the properties and associations. In the handwritten partial class you can place your business logic.  If something changes with your domain, this allows you to run the class generator again and again without fear of losing your business logic. I know that you said you are using code-first but still, partial classes can be useful.

Models are where you put business logic, and communicate with the Data Access Layer which saves & retrieves data. Your views are for presenting the user interface. The controllers are for passing information between views and models. It takes awhile to get the feel of MVC, but you are asking the right questions and are on the right track.

Hope this helps. Cheers.